# Error with sed option

Tags: linux, sed

i have created a script in my script i have variable

```
 ... line 1 ...
 ... line 2 ...
 NUM_LIGNE_POP3_SERVER_NAME=15
 ... line 4 ...
```

i execute this command:

```
POP3_SERVER_NAME=$( sed -n '$NUM_LIGNE_POP3_SERVER_NAMEs/.* = //p' /applis/DIAPASON/$REP_INSTALL/conf/mail/$FIC_FILE_MANAGER)
```

I have this error:

> sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 8: commande inconnue: `/'

Comment: you need double quote in sed to expand shell variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using double quotes to allow variable substitution, and using the braces to get your env var name.

```
POP3_SERVER_NAME=$( sed -n "${NUM_LIGNE_POP3_SERVER_NAME}s/.* = //p" /applis/DIAPASON/$REP_INSTALL/conf/mail/$FIC_FILE_MANAGER)
                           ^ ^                          ^          ^
```